# SvelteKit: CORS error only on full page load

Tags: cors, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit, django-cors-headers

I have a SvelteKit `+page.svelte` route with a corresponding `+page.ts` endpoint that fetches data from a Django server running on a different subdomain.

In Django the CORS headers are correctly specified. When I navigate from another route to my fetching route, I get all the data and everything just works fine but once I trigger a full page reload on my fetching route, I receive a:

> CORS error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

+page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    
    /** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
    export let data : Object;
</script>
<main>
    {JSON.stringify(data.books)}
</main>
```

+page.ts

```
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.my-domain.com/api/books/", {
        method: "GET",
        accept: "application/json"
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        const books = await response.json();

        return {
            books
        };
    }

    throw error(500, {
        message: "Service unavailable right now. Please try again later!"
    })
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why there is a CORS error when triggering a full page reload but not when triggering a simple navigate from another origin route?

Comment: A pagejs will run on the client and the server. So make it a server only load.

Comment: In addition to @voscausa answer, the way to do that consists simply in renaming your +page.ts to +page.server.ts (and changing the load type PageServerLoad).
You may still have +page.ts if you have some stuff to hande client-slide before the rendering

Comment: I mean, thank you for your suggestion but doesn't that avoid the problem instead of fix it? I mean, why are CORS headers not passed through in the first place when doing server side loading?

Comment: cors is a browser thing. So if you load on the server ..... And the initial load (SSR) takes place on the server.

Comment: CORS is a security standard implemented by browsers that enable scripts running in browsers to access resources located outside of the browser’s domain. https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/

Comment: I know what CORS is but isn't it detrimental to the use case of the +page.ts if it's only possible fetching data from a +page.svelte.ts? If it's possible having server side AND client side fetching within a +page.ts, why can CORS headers not just be passed to these endpoints as well?